# Is there another function that can be used to populate EoMonth?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to use the EoMonth formula in my worksheet when I try to use it, it won't generate the actual date it's supposed to generate instead it gives a 1900 date. I've used WorksheetFunction.EoMonth and Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth and Application.EoMonth but none of them seem to populate my actual Excel document. Just wondering if there is any other ways to populate EoMonth?

```
 Case "Group 1"
      If Day(DOH + 60) = 1 Then
                GracePeriod = DOH + 60
     Else
                GracePeriod = (WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(DOH + 60, 0) + 1)
            End If
    
    Case "Group 2"
        If Day(DOH + 30) = 1 Then
                GracePeriod = DOH + 30
     Else
                GracePeriod = Application.EoMonth(DOH + 30, 0) - 0
            End If
    
    Case "Group 3"
            If Day(DOH + 30) = 1 Then
                GracePeriod = DOH + 30
            Else
                GracePeriod = DateSerial(Year(DOH + 30), Month(DOH + 30) + 1, 1)
            End If
```

Picture of Excel sheet with the incorrect 1900 generated date:

[image: Picture of Excel sheet with the incorrect 1900 generated date]

Comment: What is the value of DOH ?

Comment: It appears that when the cell is assigned `GracePeriod` the value that is stored is `0`.  So my guess is that the problem is with the select case or other portion of the code and it is not even making into this block properly.

Comment: You will need to debug and step through your code line by line to see if it is even making it into this block.

Comment: Figured it out, turns out the naming conventions had an extra space in them just had to add that to the code. Instead of being "Group 1" it was "Group 1 ". It was the last thing I would imagine to be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer this question, of "another function besides EOMonth", you could construct a function that will always give you the last day of any month by evaluating the input value's month, adding one, and using first day of the next month, then subtracting one day.

Probably easier to type... If you put this in cell `H2`, you'd have it for any date in `G2`.

```
=DATE(YEAR(G2),MONTH(G2)+1,1)-1
```

Even works in Feb of 2100 by giving the CORRECT last day of Feb 28.... no leap year...

Comment: This can be simplified by using 0 as the day… `=DATE(YEAR(G2),MONTH(G2)+1,0)` No need to subtract 1 from the first day of the next month, because 0 will always return the last day of the previous month.

Comment: Figured it out, turns out the naming conventions had an extra space in them just had to add that to the code. Instead of being "Group 1" it was "Group 1 ". It was the last thing I would imagine to be wrong.

Comment: @DjC CLEVER! I didn't know that.

Comment: @alxn what a relief, however your question wasn't "what's wrong with my column"... you asked for an alternative function to `EOMONTH` which was provided. [Perhaps reveiw...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)